# Extract a section of a tgz file

Tags: windows-vista, tar, extract, gzip

I have a 28.5 GB `.tgz` file which was created on the command line of a Linux computer, compressing one folder and all its many many subfolders. I now want to extract a single sub-sub folder from that `.tgz` file, using 7zip on Windows Vista. I can't see a way to do it.

Opening the `.tgz` file in 7zip just shows the `.tar` file inside it. There doesn't seem to be any way to browse that `.tar` file and extract the section I want. I assume there is a way to do this, but I can't see it.

Simply double-clicking on the `.tar` file brings up a progress bar which runs slowly till my computer complains it's running out of space; I imagine it's trying to extract the whole thing.

Searching for "extract section of tgz" and "extract tgz subfolder" and similar found me a way to do it on [the Linux command line](https://superuser.com/q/155838/31641), but no obvious way to do it on Windows. (Most results found were about extracting *into* a subfolder, not extracting a subfolder out of the archive.)

Answer (score 0):

[WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/) handles those archives just fine. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting it using CMD and 7zip

More info here:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

Search for tar and tgz