# How do I extract files from one tarball to another tarball in one step?

Tags: command-line, tar

I have some fairly large tarball archives, from which I need to extract some files. I will later repack those files to transfer them to another server. Currently that is a two (multi) step process for me:

```
mkdir ttmp
tar -vxzf large.tgz -C ttmp/ --strip-components=<INT> <folder-to-be-extracted>
```

or alternatively with wildcards

```
mkdir ttmp
tar -vxzf large.tgz -C ttmp/ --strip-components=<INT> \
    --wildcards --no-anchored '*pattern*'
```

Then I go ahead and recompress the created folder

```
tar -vczf small.tgz ttmp/*
rm -rf ttmp
```

How can I combine these two commands into one? Like this

```
tar -x large.tgz > tar -c small.tgz
```

---

Just to show, what I already tried:

Whenever I search the terms "extract" I will end up [here](https://superuser.com/q/155838/281498) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/45349/220129) or [even here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97353). When I use the term "split" I will end up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1120095/3180795) and that is definitely not what I intend to do. When I use "repack" I end up in strange places.